Listening to Gossip network without running a full node
I didn't find any good answers to that in the web and unfortunately the docs for the solana-gossip crate aren't that good (or I'm just too new to rust).
I've come so far as to believe I need the solana_gossip::cluster_info::ClusterInfo::spy_node. Am I correct in that assumption? I can run that with a generated keypair let keypair = Keypair::new(); and let shred_version = 0;. But when I then try to listen to the returned UdpSocket via
loop {
        match udp_socket.recv_from(&mut buf) {
            Ok((bytes_received, src)) => {
                println!("Received {} bytes from {}", bytes_received, src);
                //Process gossip packet here
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error receiving data: {}", e);
            }
        }

        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }

I just get nothing. Nothing prints, nothing gets to me. What am I missing? Do I have to register a public key? Do I have to provide something else? I have set port forwarding for 8001 in my WIFI-Router and my firewall is disabled for Udp packets on port 8001 on my PC.

My goal is to receive sub-second transaction notifications without paying thousands for a geyser service. Am I too naive to think this would work?
